# Building a select list via jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a `<select>` list with jQuery. Here is what I have:

```
$('<select />')
    .attr('name', 'location')
    .val("Location 1")
    .appendTo(this);
```

The value `.val("Location 1")` does not appear in the drop down list. I'd like to have 3 locations in my list. How do I do this?

Comment: You don't add any option in the list. You have to do that creating `<option>` tags explicitly

Comment: @zerkms - oh, I see. I misunderstood what .val is doing. I thought it created the option values.

Comment: Look at the following link this might help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601952/programmatically-create-select-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `<option>` elements inside:

```
$('<select />')
    .attr('name', 'location')
    .append('<option>Location 1</option>',
            '<option>Location 2</option>',
            '<option>Location 3</option>')
    .appendTo(this);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/KUDJ6/

Answer (score 1):

Attributes are things such as size, color, etc. If you want to append to a select you will need to append options into the select tag as such:

```
$('#mySelect').append($('<option>', { value : key }).text(value));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a select element on the page and add the Locations to it..

```
$(function(){
    var html = '';
    for(var i =1;i<=3;i++){
       html += '<option value="'+ i +'"> Location ' + i + '</option>'; 
    }
    $('#dropdown1').append(html);
});
```

Check this example http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/wMC6j/