# jquery create select append document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to create a select  with options dynamically at the starting page on function document.ready.

Can i to do that?

I try, but it doesn't works.

```
 $('#form').append('<select id="myselect" name="myselect">/select>');
    $('#myselect').append('<option  title="#" value="">GREEN</option>');
```

Thank you.

Comment: **Typo?** You need to close the select tag correctly `</select>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error with your closing html tag of select element in jquery.
Also try to use [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendto) like,

```
$('<select id="myselect" name="myselect"></select>').appendTo('#form')
   //--- also check the closing html tag ^-- is proper
    .append('<option  title="#" value="">GREEN</option>');
```

Or you can use it in a single call like

```
var myselect='<select id="myselect" name="myselect">' +
                '<option  title="#" value="">GREEN</option>' +
             '</select>';
$('#form').append(myselect);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this : wrap your code inside `document.ready` and append `select` tag to form. Please make sure that `select` and `option` tag closed properly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#form').append('<select id="myselect" name="myselect"><option  title="#" value="">GREEN</option></select>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Programmatically create select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601952/programmatically-create-select-list)

This should be a better way to create the select, then you can do:

```
$('#form').append(sel);
```