# How to populate a json file values as select option in HTML

Tags: javascript, python, html, json

I have a python file which return a json file.It contains only a list like this : `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,]`
How to make this get populated in a select box in HTML page.

Code :

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
    destinations = data[]

    $.each(destinations, function(id, destination) {
        destination = destination[]
    })
});
```

what as to be done?

Comment: Not sure what you want, but this can't be right: destination = destination[], that, or your data would be something like[[[1],[2],[3]]]? Then still I'd expect the assignment to include the key for the position in the array, like destination = destination[0].

Comment: And perhaps you should include the jQuery tag and remove the python one, as it appears to be irrelevant what process it is that provides the json.

Answer (score 0):

[Previously answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601952/programmatically-create-select-list/6602002)

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
  var sel = $('<select>').appendTo('body');
  $(data).each(function() {
   sel.append($("<option>").attr('value',this).text(this));
  });
});
```

In your case not this.val and this.text as your array does not contains objects but only integers.

Comment: data is only this : `[1,2,3,4,5]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
    destinations = data[];

    $("#selectid").clear();
    $.each(destinations, function(id, destination) {
        $("#selectid").append("<option value="+destination[id]+">"+destination[id]+"</option>");
    });
});
```

Hope this is your expectation