# Getting no options into a dynamical filled select tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'd need to programmatically fill a select dropdown element with the values of an array.
I've read plenty of similar questions but could not find an answer solving my issue.

I have the following

```js
const data = {
   parameters:[{"name":"myparam","type":"enum","values":["5","10","15"]}   
   ]
}

$.each(data.parameters, function(i, parameter) {
  // parameter = {"name":myparam","type":"enum","values":["5","10","15"]}
  let param_form_id = parameter.name + "_id";

  let parameter_enum_array = new Array();
  // push all values to parameter_enum_array[]
  $.each(parameter.values, function(j, enumvalue) {
    parameter_enum_array.push(enumvalue);
  });
  let select_id = parameter.name + "_sel_id";

  // create form with empty select element
  $('<form>', {
    "id": param_form_id,
    "html": '<div class="input_field s12 l6"> <select id="' + select_id + '">  </select> </div> <div class="col s12 l6"><button class="btn blue" type="submit"> submit</button> </div>'
  }).appendTo(`.params_container`);

  // add options to select element
  var option = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < parameter_enum_array.length; i++) {
    $('<option/>').val(parameter_enum_array[i]).html(parameter_enum_array[i]).appendTo(select_id);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="params_container">

</div>
```

The resulting html code

```
<form id=myparam_id>
   <div class="input_field s12 l6">
      <select id="myparam_sel_id">  </select>
   </div>
   <div class="col s12 l6">
     <button class="btn blue" type="submit"> submit</button> 
   </div>
</form>
```

The issue is that the  is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add the data object

Comment: When you do, we can find a MUCH shorter script for you

Comment: I never seen option self closing option tags

Comment: What is the problem?  Can you post the generated html?  One way to shorten this simple change the variable name parameter_enum_array to something like values.  Here's an example of short clean code that you want to move towards.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601952/programmatically-create-select-list

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS that is valid jQuery.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically create select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601952/programmatically-create-select-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store the newly created `<form>` element object in a variable you can manipulate it with jQuery before inserting into the dom

Here I create the options using:

```
const $opts = parameter.values.map(v => new Option(v,v));
```

Then append that to the select inside the variable. When all that is done append the form to the DOM

```js
const data = {
   parameters:[{"name":"myparam","type":"enum","values":["5","10","15"]}   
   ]
}

$.each(data.parameters, function(i, parameter) { 
 
  let select_id = parameter.name + "_sel_id";

 // new form element assigned to variable
 const $form= $('<form>', {
    "id": 'param_form_id_' + i,
    "html": '<div class="input_field s12 l6"> <select id="' + select_id + '">  </select> </div> <div class="col s12 l6"><button class="btn blue" type="submit"> submit</button> </div>'
  });
  // map array of option elements
  const $opts = parameter.values.map(v => new Option(v,v));
  // insert options into select
  $form.find('#' + select_id).append($opts)
  // append whole form including the options
  $(`.params_container`).append($form);

 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="params_container">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is missing `#` for the selector at `.appendTo(select_id)`, which can be fixed with `.appendTo('#' + select_id)`.
Also here `"id": param_form_id` `param_form_id` is not defined.

---

I recommend doing this as shown below, using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and `Array.map()` in order to minimise actual DOM manipulations:

```js
const data = [{
  "name": "myparam",
  "type": "enum",
  "values": ["5", "10", "15"]
}, {
  "name": "myparam1",
  "type": "enum",
  "values": ["5", "10", "15"]
}];
const forms = [];
$.each(data, function(i, parameter) {
  const options = parameter.values.map(value => `<option>${value}</option>`).join('');
  const htmlTempate = `<div class="input_field s12 l6">
                          <select id="${parameter.name}_sel_id">${options}</select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col s12 l6">
                          <button class="btn blue" type="submit"> submit</button>
                        </div>`
  forms.push($('<form>', {
    id: 'param_form_id_' + i,
    html: htmlTempate
  }));
});

$('.params_container').append(forms);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="params_container"></div>
```

Comment: thank you for your time T J. I flagged the other answer as the solution just because it is more "compact" :-)

Comment: @user123892 that looks compact but bad for performance. It does multiple DOM updates for each form.My answer contains strings and objects expanded for readability.  They can't be made into 1liner as well.